# Specifying a Deleter for std::shared_ptr that works on all objects of a particular type or its derived types

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, delete-operator

I have the following classes in my project

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual ~Base(){};
}

class Der1: public Base
{
    public:
    virtual ~Der1(){};
}

class Der2: public Base
{
    public:
    virtual ~Der2(){};
}
```

I am holding the objects of these classes as `std::shared_ptr`. I need to provide a custom deleter for all the objects that are either of type `Base` or any of its `derived types`.

The code I want in the deleter method will be doing the same thing for all these object, say

```
class Deleter
{
    public:
    void operator()( Base * b )
    {
        //Do something
        delete b;
    }
}
```

Instead of providing the deleter during the construction of each objects like

```
std::shared_ptr< Der1 > pDer1( new Der1(), Deleter() );
std::shared_ptr< Der2 > pDer2( new Der2(), Deleter() );
```

Is there a way to specify something like "for all the shared pointers to objects of type Base  or its derived types use `Deleter` for deletion?
As deleter class is just taken in the constructor of shared_ptr how can someone specify a deleter for a particular type?

Comment: Would a type alias be acceptable?

Comment: You mean type alias for the std::shared_ptr< Base >?

Comment: I don't suppose overriding `operator delete` in `Base` is a plausible alternative.

Comment: @WhozCraig I meant specializing the std::shared pointer for all the object of Base or Der types, may be through SFINAE ( I am not that familiar with this concept ) using std::enable_if and std::is_base_of so that I would be able to specify the Deleter for such shared pointer.

Comment: yeah, now that I think about it, overriding `operator delete` would be interesting, but not very helpful regardless. Was novel to write a jig for though.

Comment: Yes, but I forgot that this only works with `std::unique_ptr`. My suggestion would be to write a function similar to make_shared, that encapsulates the deisired behavior.

Comment: @WhozCraig The operator delete is taking a void *, so I cannot deduce the type from the argument, right? Or did I misinterpreted your above statement.

Comment: @sajas it wasn't so much that as it was knowing a `Base` or one of its derivations was being deleted. That is certainly plausible, but ultimately nixed by a derivation doing the same thing to throw a wrench in the gears, and of course the members are already toast by then. Knowing something is being deleted and accessing it are somewhat to different things in this case. I'm not very sure you can do this at all. The deleter is provided to a template *member* of the `std::shared_ptr` template class, so trying anything specialization-wise at the template-class-level seems a dead end.

Comment: `Base::~Base` is already virtual. Why is this complexity needed? I don't see the problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the explanation. I think I understood that problem.

Comment: @sajas Werner's answer below has some potential if you can wedge it into your workflow paradigm. It may not be *the* solution for you but it definitely gives food for thought.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, It looks like it will work, I will try that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd write a creation/factory function in Base, returning the shared_ptr for the correct derived type. Something to this effect:

```
class Base
{
  //...public...
  template <class Derived>
  static std::shared_ptr<Base> create()
  {
    return std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived, Deleter());
  }
};
```

EDIT: Function needs to be static...

If derived has more than one parameter, that can be solved with variadic templates and perfect forwarding.

EDIT:

Like this (For more than one parameter derived constructor):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base;

struct Deleter
{
    void operator()(Base* b);
};

struct Base
{
  //...public...
  template <class Derived, class ... Args>
  static std::shared_ptr<Base> create(Args&&... args)
  {
    return std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived(std::forward<Args>(args)...), Deleter());
  }
  virtual ~Base(){}
};

void Deleter::operator()(Base* b){ delete b; }


struct Derived : Base
{
  Derived(int a, int b, int c)
  {
  }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Base> p = Base::create<Derived>(1,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```